# How do you use Fiddler with Windows Authentication?

Tags: .net, windows-authentication, fiddler

I know you can check the "Automatically Authenticate" checkbox but that uses the currently logged in user's credentials. I'm accessing a server in a different AD domain and need to supply different credentials.

So I'm logged in under `mydomain/myusername` but the credentials I need to use to access this server are `serverdomain/serverusername`. I can't login as `serverdomain\serverusername` on my laptop either. Is there somewhere in Fiddler where I can type in the credentials I want it to use?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Fiddler manual](http://fiddlerbook.com/book/):

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    // To use the current Fiddler user's credentials:
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("ServerThatDemandsCreds")) {
        oSession["x-AutoAuth"] = "(default)";
    }

    // or, to use explicit credentials...
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("ServerUsingChannelBinding")) {
        oSession["x-AutoAuth"] = "redmond\\ericlaw:MyP@$$w0rd";
    }
}
```